# Why Swift ternary operator works so strange

Tags: swift, if-statement, option-type, ternary-operator

Suppose that we have a class:

```
class Test: ExpressibleByNilLiteral {
    required init(nilLiteral: ()) {
    }

    init(_ text:String) {

    }
}
```

and we want to create instance only if some condition is **false**:

```
let condition = false
```

and use this code (1):

```
var test: Test? = condition ? Test("Z") : nil
```

as my understanding, in other languages and by [this reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID71), code above is equal to:

```
var test: Test?
if condition {
    test = Test("Z")
}
else {
    test = nil
}
```

but in fact in the first case we get not nil, but an non-optional instance of the class Test. In other words, code (1) actually works like this:

```
let test: Test? = condition ? Test("Z") : Test(nilLiteral: ())
```

moreover, expression `(condition ? Test("Z") : nil)` returns regular, non-optional value, so we can write something like:

```
let test: Test = condition ? Test("Z") : nil
```

without compilation errors.

If we try class without `ExpressibleByNilLiteral`, we get nil or compilation error, depending on variable type, as expected:

```
class Test2 {
    init(_ text:String) {

    }
}

let test2: Test2? = condition ? Test2("Z") : nil // test2 == nil
let test2: Test2 = condition ? Test2("Z") : nil // compilation error
```

More interesting things:

```
let test: Test = nil // non-optional instance initialized with nil
let test: Test? = nil // optional, nil
```

So, the question is: why we get this?

```
let test: Test? = nil // optional, nil
let test: Test? = false ? Test("Z") : nil // non-optional instance
```

This is first version of the real code with SwiftyJSON:

```
func checkResult(_ result: JSON) -> JSON? {
    return result["success"].stringValue == "true" ? result["result"] : nil
}
```

and this is "fixed" code, that works as expected by me (return nil if success != true):

```
func checkResult(_ result: JSON) -> JSON? {
    if result["success"].stringValue == "true" {
        return result["result"]
    }
    else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

later in program I use something like

```
guard let result = checkResult(json) else { return }
```

first version continues execution, as you understand, second - don't

Comment: why don't you just make your class initializer fallible based on that condition ?

Comment: Note that conformance to `ExpressibleByNilLiteral` is discouraged by the documentation. Do you actually need this or is this just an experiment? If it's the former, what do you need it for that can't be modelled by `Optional`?

Comment: I think everything works as expected, `nil as Test` is creating an instance of `Test`, using `init(nilLiteral:)`. I agree that it is confusing but that's because you are using a protocol that's not supposed to be used outside system library. That has nothing to do with ternary.

Comment: In `condition ? Test("Z") : nil`  both the 2nd and 3rd operand can be taken as non-optional Test, therefore it evaluates to a `Test` – which is then promoted to the optional `var test: Test?`.

Comment: The ternary operator is very straightforward, as OP described it in the 3rd and 4th code snippets. The confusion all stems from the use of `ExpressibleByNilLiteral`.

Comment: @LeoDabus, this Test class is not my class, it is used just for example. In my real case SwiftyJSON is ExpressibleByNilLiteral, and all works same way.

Comment: @StanislavChernischuk SwiftyJSON's JSON is a structure not a class and I don't see anywhere stating that it conforms to ExpressibleByNilLiteral. Can you post the link where you got this information from?

Comment: @LeoDabus I use IBM version, only this version is compatible with Linux (looks like it is 3.0 based): https://github.com/IBM-Swift/SwiftyJSON/blob/master/Sources/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.swift#L717 but you can find it in main repo (4.0 branch) too: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/blob/master/Source/SwiftyJSON.swift#L598

Comment: @Hamish question updated, please suggest better solution, if possible

Comment: @StanislavChernischuk Doesn't `JSON`'s subscript return a non-optional `JSON`? In that case, you can just make the method return `JSON`. Although I would avoid using `nil` with `JSON`, I would use `JSON.null` instead. Note btw that the main SwiftyJSON API has (rightfully IMO) deprecated the use of `JSON` with `ExpressibleByNilLiteral`.

Comment: @Hamish is fact I don't write something like `var json: JSON = nil` directly. This was done for me because of not the most obvious behavior of the ternary operator. My logic was simple - there is success key - return json part (api specs says that result always exists if success) or nil and unwrap value later with guard. Pretty swifty...

Comment: @StanislavChernischuk Oh sorry, I misunderstood what you were trying to achieve; you could say `return result["success"].stringValue == "true" ? result["result"] : JSON?.none` instead.

Comment: @Hamish, wow. Yes, this is it. Works like is should. `In code, the absence of a value is typically written using the nil literal rather than the explicit .none enumeration case.` - documentation. Typically, but not in some cases, huh.. :)